# Extract ICC and AIC frin pooled multi-level modeling using lmer() and mice()

Tags: r, lme4, r-mice, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to run multi-level modeling using imputed dataset.

```
imp <- mice(data, m= 20, method = "pmm")
out1 <- with(data= imp, exp = lmer(issue.atti1 ~ age+gender+race+edu+pre1+pre2+group1+(1|state))

out1.pool <- pool(out1)
summary(out1.pool)
```

The summary of the pooled output provided fixed effects and intercepts, but not ICC (intra-class correlation) and AIC.

I tried this way:

```
sapply(out1.pool $analyses, AIC)
```

But it provides the list of AIC not AIC of pooled results.

```
#[1] 18229.26 18156.71 18197.92 18180.91 18155.70 18180.63 18190.48 18268.03 18174.94 18131.65
#[11] 18174.40 18172.52 18200.76 18150.48 18156.84 18237.29 18195.19 18241.88 18225.97 18127.35
```

How could I get the pooled AIC? I don't think we should report all of AIC in the paper.

Also, I have no idea how to get ICC for this pooled model. `performance::icc()` does not work here.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: This is probably as much a statistical question as a programming question. A near-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815570/how-to-extract-aic-and-log-likelihood-from-pooled-glm?rq=1

Comment: Can you point to a **statistical** definition of what you want to do? If so, someone here can help you with the programming. If you can't, then this should go to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) instead ...

Comment: This is not possible with `mice` as far as I know.  `mean(sapply(out1.pool $analyses, AIC))` might do the trick.